# C# WPF How to start a function in WindowA by action on WindowB?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two Windows: MainWindow and AddAlarm.

AddAlarm is getting opened by a button which is in MainWindow. (MainWindow is still active)
When I typed in my data in AddAlarm, I press the "OK" button and AddAlarm get's closed. After pressing "OK" I want to activate a function which is in MainWindow.cs

But how do I do that?

Opens new window (AddAlarm)

```
private void Button_AddAlarm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        AddAlarm frm = new AddAlarm(); 
        frm.Show();
        frm.Activate();

    }
```

Pressing "OK"-button in AddAlarm window

```
private  void Button_OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

          // some code which activates function in MainWindow

    }
```

Function in MainWindow

```
 public void Refresh()
    {
        string[] refresh = new string[0];

        refresh = File.ReadAllLines("Alarms.txt");
    }
```

There might be a clever and easy solution, but I just don't know how to do that.

I appreciate your help,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This totally depends on you but here is a simple solution.

```
private void Button_AddAlarm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        AddAlarm frm = new AddAlarm(this);  // pass a reference to main window 
        frm.Show();
        frm.Activate();

    }
```

you'll need to create a `private MainWindow mainWindow;` in AddAlarm window and assign it in the constructor.

Then

```
private  void Button_OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

          this.mainWindow.Refresh();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

More complicated, but more "idiomatic", would be to rely on callback events (like an `AlarmAdded` event with an `Alarm` parameter which would be registered right after the `AddAlarm` is created and raised by the `AddAlarm` window when it's done).

The approach I would probably take would be to just open `AddAlarm` modally--that way you can read the information you need from the `AddAlarm` window in the same block.

```
private void Button_AddAlarm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddAlarm frm = new AddAlarm(); 
    // ShowDialog waits until AddAlarm is closed before returning
    frm.ShowDialog();
    // Recommended to add a check on frm.DialogResult to verify whether the user OK'd or Cancelled.
    if (frm.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok) {
        AlarmSettings settings = frm.AlarmSettings;
        Alarm createdAlarm = new Alarm (AlarmSettings);
    }
}
```